# How can I run a block of ruby code from Terminal.app?

Tags: ruby, command-line, terminal

I'm specifically using OS X Terminal.app for command line stuff, but this question may also apply to other command line tools.

Say I want to run this block of ruby code from the command line:

```
Cats.each do |cat|
  cat.name = 'Mommy'

  cat.kittens each do |kitten|
    kitten.color = "Brown"
  end
end
```

Right now if I copy/paste that it just gets broken up and doesn't execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that Terminal.app is not itself a Ruby interpreter. You'll want to fire up `irb` to get an interactive Ruby console:

```
user@host # irb

irb(main):001:0> Cats.each do |cat|
irb(main):002:1*   cat.name = 'Mommy'
irb(main):003:1> 
irb(main):004:1*   cat.kittens each do |kitten|
irb(main):005:2*     kitten.color = "Brown"
irb(main):006:2>   end
irb(main):007:1> end

NameError: uninitialized constant Cats
    from (irb):1
    from :0
```

There are [other tricks](http://www.rubycentral.com/pickaxe/irb.html) you can use to run `irb` in the context of a particular script.

Answer (score 26):

```
ruby -e "Cats.each do |cat|
  cat.name = 'Mommy'

  cat.kittens each do |kitten|
    kitten.color = 'Brown'
  end
end"
```

Answer (score 1):

Well first you need to run irb (or pass the code to the interpreter using `ruby -e`) as the terminal doesn't have any idea what that block of code is or how to interpret it.

After that you should be able to run in by pasting it in as you say.